# Debugging table permissions for a windows user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server 2008 Database.

I created a few Windows users, added them to a specific database, and granted them read write access with the scripts below:

```
CREATE LOGIN [PRUDENTIAL\X208476] FROM WINDOWS 
    WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english];

Use client
GO
CREATE USER [PRUDENTIAL\X208476] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo
GO
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [PRUDENTIAL\X208476]
GO
exec sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, [PRUDENTIAL\X208476]
GO
```

They run a basic insert command as follows and receive the error shown below:

```
INSERT INTO [client].[dbo].[admin_user_role]
           ([user_id]
           ,[role_id]
           ,[last_acty_oper_id]
           ,[last_acty_dtm])
     VALUES
           ('X208480'
           ,'ADMIN'
           ,'x163798'        
           ,'2017-04-06 11:12:19.597')

Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
The insert permission was denied on object ‘admin_user_role’, database ‘client’, schema ‘dbo’.
```

I tested this with another colleague of mine and he has no issue inserting into the table.

What other check/debugging can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just throwing it out there -- you may not want to paste your company name and logins on the internet. Some may consider that a 'security risk'.

Comment: What do you get when you this? `EXECUTE AS USER = 'PRUDENTIAL\X208476';  
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.admin_user_role', 'OBJECT')   
    ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name ;    
REVERT;  
GO`

Answer (score 0):

Please run this code to find out if you have a deny on that user under the column state_desc.

```
SELECT permission_name, 
   state_desc, 
   type_desc, 
   U.NAME, 
   Object_name(major_id) 
FROM   sys.database_permissions P 
   JOIN sys.tables T 
     ON P.major_id = T.object_id 
   JOIN sysusers U 
     ON U.uid = P.grantee_principal_id
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the database user you have to ensure it is linked to the SQL Login you created for the windows account.

Instead of your code:

```
...
GO
CREATE USER [PRUDENTIAL\X208476] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo
GO
...
```

Try this code here:

```
...
GO 
CREATE USER [PRUDENTIAL\X208476] FOR LOGIN [PRUDENTIAL\X208476] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo
GO
...
```

In this way the SQL Login (which is based on a Windows Account) is linked to the database user on creation.

- SQL Logins are stored in the **master** database.
- Database Users are stored in the **client** (user's) database.

#### Finding all the permissions of a user

And if you would like to retrieve all the permissions of all your users in the **client** database, you could use the script provided in the stackoverflow article:

[SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7048839/1820861)

The answer from Sean Rose seems to [incorporate the most features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30040784/1820861)

Comment: For windows login that is not mandatory but I would do that as a best practice.